# Teradata loop for dates, column adding within loop

Tags: sql, loops, syntax, teradata

I have a table where every row is transaction and there are few columns: clients IDs and dates for every transaction.

I am trying to write a query which will give a table where column N shows number of clients whose first transaction happened in month N made transactions in months: N, N+1, N+2, ...

For example (desired table for 3 months data):

```
1       2      3 

100    90      78
80     80
60
```

First row of the column 1 shows number of clients whose first transaction happened in month 1, second row shows how many of this clients stayed after 1 month, third row - after two month etc

My current query (Year is a column wit year for the date, like 2017, month is a number of month like 1 for January):

```
    WITH not_in AS(
       SELECT ID, Year, month
       FROM table
       WHERE trans_date<date "2017-01-01"),
     
    ID_in AS(
       SELECT ID, Year, month
       FROM table
       WHERE trans_date BETWEEN date "2017-01-01" AND  date "2017-01-31"
    ),

    from_this AS(
       SELECT ID, Year, month
       FROM table 
            )

 

SELECT Year, Month, count(distinct ID)

FROM from_this

WHERE ID IN (select  ID from ID_in)

AND

ID NOT IN (select  ID from not_in)

GROUP BY 1,2

ORDER BY 1,2
```

But this gives only one column (for January 2017) of the desired table. I need to change dates for other months in 2017, 2018 and so on manually.

How to avoid this?

I guess, it should be looped somehow. And I think, I should create volatile table and add columns to it within loop, then select * from it.

Also I can not find an instruction for variables declaration and while loops in Teradata, any clearifications are appreciated.

Comment: In Teradata, loops and variables are supported only within a stored procedure. But for best performance you should generally avoid loops and use SQL features. Can you clarify the desired result? For example, what does each row represent?

Comment: First row of the column 1 shows number of clients whose first transaction happened in month 1, second row shows how many of this clients stayed after 1 month, third row - after two month etc

Comment: How many columns should be returned? Is the first month always the same, e.g. Jan?

Comment: First column in the desired table is alwaya the first month, second is the second etc